# htaccess and RewriteRule Chain

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewrite-module

I have a problem with htaccess rewrite_mode.
when i use multiple $_GET variables in these rules, first variable get the name file that be first $_GET variable. please help me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase   /ts/
RewriteRule     ^(.+)/$                  ts.php?a=$1 [C]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.+)/$             ts.php?a=$1&b=$2 [C]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.*)/(.+)/$        ts.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [C]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.+)/$   ts.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [C,L]
```

this is output for "localhost/ts/1/"

```
Array ( [a] => 1 )
```

this is output for "localhost/ts/1/2/"

```
Array ( [a] => ts.php [b] => 2 )
```

this is output for "localhost/ts/1/2/3/"

```
Array ( [a] => ts.php [b] => 2 [c] => 3 )
```

this is output for "localhost/ts/1/2/3/4/5/6/"

```
Array ( [a] => ts.php/2/3 [b] => 4 [c] => 5 [d] => 6 )
```

Comment: That's because in a .htaccess context after rewriting is done, the new URL is fed into the rewriting process _again_ - and `ts.php?a=foo` matches `^(.+)/`. You can avoid this f.e. by simply excluding physically existing files from rewriting using a `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the chain flags and just reverse your RewriteRules, like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase   /ts/

RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.+)/$   ts.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3&d=$4 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.*)/(.+)/$        ts.php?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)/(.+)/$             ts.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
RewriteRule     ^(.+)/$                  ts.php?a=$1 [L]
```